# How to call a stat from a class into a function - Python

Tags: python, function, class, self

I am struggling to create a health/anger (variables) drop when making the user fight a knight. I have defined a class called kingsmen, that is very simple and used for each knight, but I keep getting told that I am not calling the class properly. I'm not sure how to explain it. Below is the code for the class and for the knight, and the error message will be at the bottom. Some of the print spacing is weird (the ones with ''' ''') because the site is being difficult. 
Thank you!

Class:

```
class kingsmen:                                   

    def __init__(self):
        self.stats = {}

    def attributes(self):                                  
        health=15
        anger=7
        self.stats["health"] = 15                     #storing default health count
       self.stats["anger"] = 7
       return self.stats
   def warning(self):                                #players will see this message when meeting a knight
       print ('A kingsmen! Prepare for battle!')
   def noise(self):
       print ("H e y ,  i t ' s  a  v i l l a g e r !")        #have these attributes later. 
   def death(self):
       if healh == 0:
           print ('''DEFEATED''')
```

Knight:

```
def rknightOne(kingsmen):           #r stands for random, he will be one of 5 random villains you can face
    rknightOne=kingsmen()
    #while health in kingsmen.stats()!= 0 and anger != 0:
    if action == 'attack':
        for health in rknightOne.attributes:
            health=health-1
            print health
        print_slowly ('I did not feel a thing. Ha ha ha!')
        healthDrop(user)
    elif action == 'mercy':
        for anger in rknightOne.attributes:
            anger=anger-1
        print_slowly ('Huh. I feel something warm inside.')
    elif action=='run':
        print_slowly ('Not so fast!')
    else:
        print_slowly ("Jeez this guy is looney. I CAN'T UNDERSTAND YOU!")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/REDEMPTION/Redemption Game V1.py", line 678, in <module>
    print randomKnight()
File "C:/Python27/REDEMPTION/Redemption Game V1.py", line 440, in randomKnight
    print random.choice([rknightOne(kingsmen), rknightTwo(kingsmen), rknightThree(kingsmen), rknightFour(kingsmen), rknightFive(kingsmen)])
File "C:/Python27/REDEMPTION/Redemption Game V1.py", line 178, in rknightOne
for health in rknightOne.attributes:
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable
```

The random function it's talking about is just cycling through 5 knights that could pop up. This is the code in case it's helpful:

```
def randomKnight():
    print random.choice([rknightOne(kingsmen), rknightTwo(kingsmen), rknightThree(kingsmen), rknightFour(kingsmen), rknightFive(kingsmen)])
```

Comment: I suggest not having `self.stats = {}` and a method `def stats(self)`. You should change the name of one of them. Once you clear up your current error, you will most likely face another error because of the name clashing.

Comment: I fixed the indentation. Still getting used to this site. Sorry about that, what's there now is what appears in my IDLE

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
for health in kingsmen.stats():
```

with one of the following statements

```
for health in kingsmen.stats: # if you don't want to call the method
for health in kingsmen.stats(some_argument): # or if you want to call the method provide arguments
```

Reason you are getting this error is that you have defined both

```
self.stats = {}
```

and

```
def stats(self)
```

in kingsmen class, so it's confusing you.

Comment: for health in kingsmen.stats: got this error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Python27/REDEMPTION/Redemption Game V1.py", line 677, in <module>
        print randomKnight()
      File "C:/Python27/REDEMPTION/Redemption Game V1.py", line 439, in randomKnight
        print random.choice([rknightOne(kingsmen), rknightTwo(kingsmen), rknightThree(kingsmen), rknightFour(kingsmen), rknightFive(kingsmen)])
      File "C:/Python27/REDEMPTION/Redemption Game V1.py", line 177, in rknightOne
        for health in kingsmen.stats:
    TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable

Comment: What kingsmen.stats return is something not iterable, you are trying to iterate it in for loop. Now, this is another error, which is irrelevant with your question.

Comment: I am putting in "health" and self and kingsmen but none of them are functioning. What would you mean by some_argument if not kingsmen, self, or the stat itself?

Comment: I meant, theres no method 'stats' accepts zero arguments, you probably tried to use 'stats' object, or forgot to pass argument into method. And possible reason for this was using the same names for the method and the object. The error message in your question was for this.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest revision of your code, it is clear what you are trying to do now. The error message you are seeing is telling you that you cannot iterate over an instance method. That is exactly what you are trying to do. You are trying to loop over kingsmen.attributes which is a method in your class. You cannot do that. Your method is actually returning a dictionary, and the result of executing that method is something you can iterate over. So you actually want to iterate over the result of calling attributes(). However, there is one more problem to clear up before that as I'll explain below.

In order to be able to properly call attributes, you have to instantiate your class ([documentation on classes and objects in Python](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/class)) first.

What you are doing is not executing the method, furthermore, not instantiating the class to be able to access and execute the method.

To resolve this, your line here:

```
for health in kingsmen.attributes:
```

You need to first instantiate your class, and then use the object from your class to call the attributes method. The return of that attributes method as you implemented will return the dictionary that you are trying to iterate over. So, your code should look like this:

```
my_kingsmen = kinsgmen()
for health in my_kinsgmen.attributes():
```

Comment: To be honest, I asked my professor what was going wrong and he told me to use the self.stats={} so I am not sure what to rename it, or which I should be calling with rknightOne

Comment: If your professor said to use self.stats = {}. Then change your `def stats` to something else.

Comment: The code is now:
    def attributes(self):
        health=15
        anger=7
        self.stats["health"] = 15                    
        self.stats["anger"] = 7

Error:
  File "C:/Python27/REDEMPTION/Redemption Game V1.py", line 179, in rknightOne
    health=health-1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Don't paste code in the comments. If you need to update code, do it in the original post. Please read my answer again (I made an important change). I think I realized what you are trying to do. Read it carefully.

Comment: It is clear what you are trying to do now. Read my latest update.